# Can I get a refresh_token using cURL from the command line, or in Salesforce.com itself?

Tags: php, curl

I have a web server which uses Salesforce's REST API from PHP. It needs permanent access, to occasionally do things like create opportunities, accounts, and other objects.

I don't want to store my username and password on the web server - I'd rather use a permanently non-expiring refresh_token to generate new access tokens when needed.

My web server's logic isn't triggered by a user it can redirect to a webpage to sign in. Is there a Salesforce.com page I can use to generate the refresh token, and permanently store the refresh token on my webserver so the web server can access my "Connected App" to use the REST API?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be better off using JWT for oAuth.  It's more predictable behavior. Here is a PHP github library that I've used that has a lot of the code  - https://github.com/adhocore/php-jwt

To read up on the JWT flow, check this out:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0